# How to order the item categories in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, c#-4.0

I am having 20 records

I want to order the records in terms of `Priority` field.

`Priority` field is having 3 values( `High, Medium, Low` )

I want to display the records in `High, Medium, Low` records in sequence respectively.

Below is `C#` version ---> I need this to do in **javascript**

```
`var groupedRecords = records.OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority == "High").ThenByDescending(x > x.Priority == "Medium").ThenByDescending(x > x.Priority == "Low")`
```

In Javascript,

`var csvRecords = priorities.split(',');` // Now I am getting the csv with mixed orders. I need in sequence. 
        That is I want to get **first** all High records, **then** Medium records and **atlast** Low records.

Comment: What does `var csvRecords = priorities.split(',');` return ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take look at below simple code:

```js
var points = [{Name: "House",Priority :"High"}, {Name: "Travel",Priority :"Medium"}, {Name: "Children",Priority :"High"}, {Name: "Personal Loan",Priority :"Low"}, {Name: "Car",Priority :"Medium"}, {Name: "Shopping",Priority :"Low"}];


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(points);

function myFunction() {
   var priorityArray = ["High", "Medium","Low"]
    points.sort(function(a, b){
        var firstPrio = priorityArray.indexOf( a.Priority) ;
        var secPrio = priorityArray.indexOf(b.Priority)
        return firstPrio -secPrio 
    });
    document.getElementById("sortedArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(points);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Sort it</button>
<br/><br/>
Original Array:

<p id="demo"></p>

Sorted Array:

<p id="sortedArray"></p>
```

I hope it will help you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Condensed version using constants for sort order:

**Data:**

```
var data = [
    {
        name: 'Andy',
        priority: 'High'
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        priority: 'Low'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tim',
        priority: 'Medium'
    },
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        priority: 'Medium'
    },
    {
        name: 'Lucas',
        priority: 'Medium'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        priority: 'High'
    },
    {
        name: 'Fred',
        priority: 'Low'
    }
];
```

**Code:**

```
var SORT_ASC = -1;
var SORT_DESC = 1;

function sort_by_priority ( order ) {
    var prs = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'];
    data.sort(function ( a, b ) {
        var x = prs.indexOf(a.priority);
        var y = prs.indexOf(b.priority);

        if ( x < y ) return -1 * order;
        if ( x > y ) return 1 * order;
        return 0;
    });
}
```

**Test:**

```
sort_by_priority(SORT_DESC);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8khdgraz/1/)

#### Code

```js
var data = [];
var priority = ["low", "medium", "high"];

function createData() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) % 3);
    var p = priority[index];
    data.push({
      "index": i,
      "Priority": p
    });
  }
}

function createLI() {
  var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
  var li = "";
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    li += "<li> " + row.index + " : " + row.Priority + " </li>";
  });
  ul.innerHTML = li;
}

function sortList(sortOrder) {
  var order = (sortOrder == 'desc') ? -1 : 1;
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var p1, p2;
    priority.forEach(function(row, index) {
      if (a.Priority == row)
        p1 = index;
      if (b.Priority == row)
        p2 = index;
    })
    if (p1 < p2) return -1 * order;
    if (p1 > p2) return 1 * order;
    return 0;
  });
  createLI();
}

(function() {
  createData();
  createLI();
})()
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
<button onclick="sortList('asc')">Asc Sort</button>
<button onclick="sortList('desc')">Desc Sort</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `val + "\.\\w+(?=.*,)", "g"` to match `val` followed by any character followed by any alphanumeric character ; where `val` is `"High"` , `"Medium"` , or `"Low"` stored in an array iterated within `Array.prototype.forEach()` , utilize `Array.prototype.concat()` to flatten resulting array `res` containing input text sorted from "High" to "Medium" to "Low" . Use `res.push()` to return three arrays sorted from "High" to "Medium" to "Low"

```js
var priorities = "High:1,Medium:2,Low:3,Low:4,Medium:5,High:6,Medium:7,"
                 + "High:8,Low:9,Low:10,Medium:11,High:12,Low:13,Medium:14,"
                 + "High:15,High:16,Low:17,Medium:18,Low:19,High:20";

var keys = ["High", "Medium", "Low"], res = [];
keys.forEach(function(val) {
  res = res.concat(priorities.match(new RegExp(val + "\.\\w+(?=.*,)", "g")))
});
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res)
```